# Issues when write `loop ... collect` in macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

guys.

Today I want to write sigma macro to calculate the sum from the flexible expression input.

The code below is I written this afternoon. But it does not work follow my purpose.

```
(defmacro sigma (exp ll)
  `(+ ,@(loop for i in ll collect
             (progn (setf (elt exp 1) i)
                    (print exp)
                    exp)))
  )

>>(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(sigma (+ 1 2) (2 3 4))))
>>(+ 2 2) 
  (+ 3 2) 
  (+ 4 2) 
  (+ (+ 4 2) (+ 4 2) (+ 4 2))
```

I want it works `(+ (+ 2 2) (+ 3 2) (+ 4 2))` but `loop collect` give me the weird answer.

Why does it work like this? Do I have some methods to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a freshly consed list, then `copy-list` is a way:

```
(defmacro sigma (exp ll)
  `(+ ,@(loop for i in ll and exp1 = (copy-list exp)
              do (setf (second exp1) i)
              collect exp1)))
```

Nested backquote expressions are also possible:

```
(defmacro sigma ((op arg0 &rest args) ll)
  (declare (ignore arg0))
  `(+ ,@(loop for i in ll collect `(,op ,i ,@args))))
```

Answer (score 6):

You are mutating literal data (quoted). If you agree that during that loop the list `(+ 1 2)`, bound to exp, is the same one in each iteration and that you mutate the second element in each iteration it's easy to imagine that a list that has collected the same list `exp` 3 times would have 3 exactly the same elements with the very last mutation of the second element.

This is by no means a feature in macros. Doing mutation on all quoted data can produce such result. The standard dictates the result would be undefined so no implementer needs address this and you get the unexpected behaviour out of other aspects of the particular implementation.

A compiled file might join all quoted data together to become one and the same such that `'(+ 1 2)` other places in the code might get affected by this macro as well.

To fix this simply don't mutate:

```
(defmacro sigma ((op r &rest rest) ll)
  `(+ ,@(loop :for i :in ll 
              :collect (list* op i rest))))

(macroexpand-1 '(sigma (+ 1 2) (2 3 4)))
; ==> (+ (+ 2 2) (+ 3 2) (+ 4 2))
```

The nice thing about this is that you are guaranteed to have at least two arguments in the template.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(sigma (x) (2 3 4)))
; ==> *** - SIGMA: (X) does not match lambda list element (OP R &REST REST)
```

Comment: Even if he weren't mutating it, he's collecting the same `exp` object each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar I remember I once `NCONC`-ed the same argument twice to get a double sized list  :-)